# Z-ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name (PLSQL)

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql

I kind of new on dynamic variables in plsql. 
I am getting an error "invalid host/bind variable name" on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
statement. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_CLASS_CONFIG_DML (pBuCode     VARCHAR2,
                                                 pMyPKId     VARCHAR2,
                                                 pMyName     VARCHAR2,
                                                 pMyId       VARCHAR2,
                                                 pRemarks    VARCHAR2,
                                                 pUserId     VARCHAR2)
AS
    v_table      VARCHAR2 (50);
    v_lastdate   DATE;
    --bindable var.
    v_pkey       VARCHAR2 (12) := pMyPKId;
    v_myname     VARCHAR2 (30) := pMyName;
    v_bucode     VARCHAR2 (4) := pBuCode;
    v_myid       VARCHAR2 (12) := pMyId;
    v_remarks    VARCHAR2 (50) := pRemarks;
    v_lastid     VARCHAR2 (8) := pUserId;
BEGIN
    v_lastdate := SYSDATE;
    v_table := v_bucode || '_WORKSHEET_CONFIG';

    --Error happens on this part
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
           'insert into '
        || v_table
        || '(pk_id,my_name,my_id,remarks,last_user,last_date)
      values(:pkey,:myname,:myid,:remarks,:user,:lastdate)'
        USING v_pkey,
              v_myname,
              v_myid,
              v_remarks,
              v_lastid,
              v_lastdate;

    --end comment
    COMMIT;
    RETURN;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        ROLLBACK;
END MY_CLASS_CONFIG_DML;
```

Comment: You are passing in `v_lastdate` in the list of bind variables, but you haven't declared v_lastdate in the declaration section. That might (will!) be a problem...

Comment: @Boneist, Thanks, added it already, however I am still getting invalid host/bind error. Is there any format for Execute Immediate statement?

Comment: By the way, the exception hider doesn't seem helpful. If the `insert` doesn't work, what is there to roll back? If it fails due to space shortage or corrupted index block or something, wouldn't you want to escalate that, rather than silently undoing everything done in the session since the last commit, whenever that was?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Robertson thanks for the info, I think i got it. Have a nice day!

Comment: The code works for me, after I hardcoded it with my own demo table name. A simple demo that reproduced the behaviour would help (and in creating it you might even spot the issue yourself).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Good day to you, Thanks for your effort, After I reviewed all the codes in my PLSQL, the actual code have some reserved word as a variable. It is already ok. Hope you would help me again next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `:user` by another keyword: `:myuser` or `:lastid`. The colon should make it possible to use the reserved keyword "user", but this is the only problem i see.